# Unable to give correct path in wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Suppose their is a wordpress theme say zumper. Apart from files such as footer.php, header.php their are other folders such as
layouts
inc

suppose I have a file america.php in layouts folder and york.php in inc folder

what is the correct path and correct way to include york.php from inc folder to america.php, which is in layout folder

Summarizing - 
america.php -  Layout Folder
york.php - inc folder

I want to include york.php in america.php what is the correct way specially the correct path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

[`get_template_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) and or [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory)

E.g. in `zumper/layouts/america.php`

```
<?php

include get_template_directory() . '/inc/york.php';
//etc...
```

Note:

#### get_template_directory

> Retrieves the absolute path to the directory of the current theme.

#### get_stylesheet_directory

> Retrieve stylesheet directory Path for the current theme/child theme.

So if your theme is a child theme and or you want to provide the ability for a child theme to override your parent include then use the latter.

Comment: It worked. i was using something like this -
<?php get_template_part('/inc/york.php'); ?>

Comment: Done. Accepted.

Comment: `get_template_part` would also work but in your use case you need to drop the `.php` extension off the argument as the extension gets appended in the function itself. `get_template_part('inc/york')` - also `get_template_part()` first searches for a child theme before looking in the parent theme, so it's good to use that when you want to ensure child themes can override your parent theme file. It is acceptable to use `get_template_part()` in your use case also.

Comment: Ok sir.I will try with that Option also.